# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist - Error selecting key or setting result to parameter object

Tags: java, sql, sequence

I have a database table with a sequence in the db script

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_CLAIMS MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE
GO
```

Up until yesterday the insert statement worked fine

```
<insert id="xxxx" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="PK_EXTRACTID" keyProperty="xxxxx" parameterType="xxxxxx">
       <selectKey keyProperty="xxxx" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
           SELECT SEQ_CLAIMS.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
       </selectKey>
       INSERT
           INTO CLAIMS_INBOX_EXTRACT (
                   PK_EXTRACTID,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xxxx,
                   xxxx,xxx,xxxx,xxxx,xxxxx, xxx)
           VALUES(
               #{xxx}, #{xxx}, #{xxx}, #{xxx}, #{xxx},
               #{xxx}, #{xx}, #{xxx}, #{xxx}, #{xxxx},
               #{xxx}, #{xxxx}, #{xxx}
           )
   </insert>
```

I am now receiving an error that the sequence does not exist.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Error selecting key or setting result to parameter object. Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

Would anyone have an idea of what might have gone wrong?

Comment: `GO` isn't a valid SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved, privileges on sequence were lost and needed re-granted.

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON <table_name> TO < >
GRANT SELECT ON <sequence_name/view_name> TO < >
```